# ASP.NET WebAPI security - Refresh token and client secret

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I'm trying to create SPA using Angular and Asp.net WebAPI as data server.

For me is a question how to secure my website correctly...

OAuth tokens is a popular solution which mean that I should store auth_token,
refresh_toke, client id and client secret somewhere.

Client_secret should not be exposed to the front-end level.

Does it mean that I need to have a new Asp.Net Mvc layer which will store safely client secret?

And than my flow will looks like :

1. Angular (send new token request)
2. Asp.Net Mvc (use refresh_token + client secret from session and call web api)
3. Asp.Net WebApi (return new access_token)

So the main problem how to safely store refresh_token and client_secret and get a new access token in Asp.Net WebApi?